# Error : Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas

Found this snippet code to basically increase my negative reviews to better train my model. When I went to run it through I am getting this error. Looks to be around the idx. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np

labels, num = np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True)
#print(labels)
u=min(labels)
intial = 1

#set the desired size of the oversampled cells
maxcnt = np.int(max(num)/2)

for labl, n in zip(labels, num):
    x0 = X_train[y_train==labl]
    y0 = y_train[y_train==labl]
    # print (x0)

    remain = maxcnt
    print (remain)
    while remain >= n;
        if label == u and initial == 1;
            X_Train = x0
            y_Train = y0
            remain -= n
            initial = 0
        else:
            X_Train = np.concatenate((X_Train, x0), axis=0)
            y_Train = np.concatenate((y_Train, y0), axis=0)
            remain -= n
    if remain > 0 and remain < n:
        idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(y0)), remain, replace=False)
       #print(idx)
        X_Train = np.concatenate((X_Train, x0[idx]), axis=0)
        y_Train = np.concatenate((y_Train, y0[idx]), axis=0)
        remain -= n
X_Train, y_Train = shuffle(X_Train, y_Train)
np.unique(X_Train, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: without some data,it is hard to say for sure, but the error means that when you do `x0[idx]` or `y0[idx]`, some of the element of `idx` are not index of x0 or y0, and with how they are built above, it seems fair to assume `x0` or `y0` are not index from 0 to `len(y0)`, which are the bounds for the element of `idx`. maybe try `idx = np.random.choice(y0.index, remain, replace=False)`, like this you pick element directly existing from y0 index